# calling the default constructor

Tags: c++

```
class base {
    int i;
public:
    base()
    {
        i = 10;
        cout << "in the constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base a;// here is the point of doubt
    getch();
}
```

What is the difference between `base a`  and `base a()`?

in the first case the constructor gets called but not in the second case!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The second one is declaring a function a() that returns a base object.  :-)

Answer (score 23):

`base a` declares a variable `a` of type `base` and calls its default constructor (assuming it's not a builtin type).

`base a();` declares a function `a` that takes no parameters and returns type `base`.

The reason for this is because the language basically specifies that in cases of ambiguity like this anything that can be parsed as a function declaration should be so parsed. You can search for "C++ most vexing parse" for an even more complicated situation.

Because of this I actually prefer `new X;` over `new X();` because it's consistent with the non-new declaration.

Comment: But does `new X;` act the same as `new X()`?

Answer (score -6):

In C++, you can create object in two way:

1. Automatic (static)
2. Dynamic

The first one uses the following declaration :

```
base a; //Uses the default constructor
base b(xxx); //Uses a object defined constructor
```

The object is deleted as soon as it get out of the current scope.

The dynamic version uses pointer, and you have the charge to delete it :

```
base *a = new base(); //Creates pointer with default constructor
base *b = new base(xxx); //Creates pointer with object defined constructor

delete a; delete b;
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be `base * a = new base()` ??

Comment: Is this answer really relevant to the question? You didn't address `base b()`

Comment: What is the proper way for dynamically allocating an object using a default constructor in C++? Is it `base* a = new base();` **OR** `base* a = new base;`? What's the difference?

Comment: You can see that at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/637404